# Inheritance and Polymorphism in NHibernate how do I get the actual instance

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

This is the situation. I have 4 tables and classes, Order, OrderItem, Product and Cristal.

Product is a concrete class and a base class for Cristal. I was testing that inserting a Cristal and then retrieving it as a Product, produce a Cristal istance. So far so good.

Now the problem. I persist an Order with Items that contains instances of Products and Cristals in the 'Product' property. When I retrieve an Order object from the database, the Product property in the OrderItem instace is always a Product instance. Where must be a Cristal, there is a Product with the common fields loaded right, but obviously, I can't have access to the specific Cristal fields.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

**Mapping for Products and its subclass Cristal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
       assembly="MyNamespace"
       namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="Product" table="Products">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Code" column="code" type="string" not-null="true" />

    <union-subclass name="Cristal" table="Cristals">
      <property name="Esf" column="esf" precision="5" scale="3" not-null="true" />
      <property name="Cil" column="cil" precision="5" scale="3" not-null="true" />
      <property name="Diameter" column="diameter" type="int" not-null="true" />
    </union-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping for Order**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="MyNamespace"
               namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="Order" table="Orders">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Number" column="number" type="int" not-null="true" />
    <set name="Items" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="idOrder" not-null="true" />
      <one-to-many class="OrderItem"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping for OrderItem**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="MyNamespace"
               namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="OrderItem" table="OrderItems">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>

    <property name="Price" column="price" precision="15" scale="3" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Order" column="idOrder" foreign-key="FK_OrderItems" not-null="true"  />
    <many-to-one name="Product" column="idProduct" foreign-key="FK_ProductOrderItems"  />

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: According to [good design practice](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf) you shouldn't inherit from a concrete class. Make two concrete classes with the same abstract base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked with NHibernate, but I think I know what the problem might be.

Since Product is a concrete class, NHibernate won't look for any Cristals. That is, NHibernate won't include Cristal in the join. Make an abstract base class (ProductBase) and two concrete implementations, one for Product and another for Cristal.

Comment: Yeah, I see that probably is not the best design. I will redesign the Model. Thank you very much Torbjörn!